# Set mysql.user.max_connections for multiple users

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In Mariadb I'd like to update `max_connections` on multiple user entries like this:

```
> UPDATE mysql.user SET max_connections = 10 WHERE User = "foo";
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

It looks like it's not possible.

The reason I try this is because I didn't find a way of running the `ALTER USER` statement for multiple hosts:

```
> ALTER USER foo WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 20;
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'foo'
```

I don't want to have to do this for every `Host` separately. How can I set `max_connections` for all entries with the same username but different host?

I have to do this:

```
ALTER USER foo@remote1 WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 20;
ALTER USER foo@remote2 WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 20;
ALTER USER foo@remote3 WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 20;
```

which is cumbersome because I first have to figure out all the remotes to update them all to the same value.

Comment: With MySQL you can do this
:mysql> CREATE USER 'francis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'frank'
    ->     WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
    ->          MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
    ->          MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
    ->          MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;

But max_connections is a SERVER not user setting.

Comment: @DaveStokes The query `ALTER USER foo@localhost WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 20;` (note the `@localhost`) works fine. It's just that I don't want to do this for all the user entries there are.

Comment: If only there were a way to write code to perform actions repetitively... maybe we could call this a "circle". Except one part would change each time through the circle, we could call this a "variant." ;-)

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm looking for a simple dumb solution. If I have to script a proper solution, I will just not bother and repeat the lines instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need update MySQL server options file config (ie. /etc/my.cnf)

```
[mysqld]
max_connections = 50000 // max connection of MySql server
max_user_connections = 100 // per user
```

If you want to set per user/host, you have to alter for each like

```
ALTER USER 'user1'@'localhost' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
ALTER USER 'user2'@'localhost' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 5;
ALTER USER 'user3'@'localhost' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 20;
```

Note: I don't think that need this configuration cuz It should be managed by a connection pool.
Ref doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way to update the limits for multiple entries at the same time. This way is very cumbersome to automate becauser there are multiple entries per user.